# Bootstrap style not working against Angular2 components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap style not working against Angular2 components.

in the following angular2 component not working as bootstrap fluid container in ui. in works will if I use 'container-fluid' inside the component with div element.

Ex: (Not working)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'gn-app',
    viewProviders: [],
    moduleId: module.id,
    template:
        `<gn-layout class="container-fluid"
        (window:resize)="gnOnResize($event)"
        </gn-layout>
    `,
   directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LayoutComponent]
})
```

Working Code

```
<gn-layout>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class"row">
          <gn-container></gn-container>
      </div>
   </div>
</gn-layout>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because browsers don't recognize those components as HTML elements, so they don't apply the default styles on them. You have to add `display:block` to the component and it will render correctly.

```
@Component({
    styles : [`
        :host {
            display: block;
        }
    `]
})
```

That will work. You can read this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5960) where is being discussed to add `display:block` by default.

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BzrXaPfZFGDZ0tQU0FWa?p=preview) with an example working. To see the difference, remove the `styles` property from the component.

Comment: is it required for all component?

Comment: @NatarajanGanapathi sadly looks like it is. I'm not aware of any way to make it by default. You can use in your css something like `my-app * { display:block; }` but that may affect others thing that you don't want affect.

Comment: ya.. it is good idea. Thanks @Eric Martinez.  I am creating my own component with some `xx-` prefix. so that  I can do like `xx-app xx-* {display:block;}` or `xx-* {display:block; }`. is it good way to do ?

Comment: It would be a really good idea to prefix your components and then use what you suggested, I would do that while there's nothing by default.

Comment: sadly it did work if I use like `xx-* { display: block; }`

Comment: it works if I use like `._nghost-xli-*{ display: block; }`