# Angular/CSS: does not take formatting

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm surprised that my formatting will not be accepted. If I'm in the index and add there

```
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
...
</main>
```

Then my design is displayed correctly and "ABC" is on the right side.
But if I move it to the app.component.html, then the formatting seems to be misrepresented.
At first I thought this could be the following problem, but `display:block;` doesn't solve it :

[Bootstrap style not working against Angular2 components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191317/bootstrap-style-not-working-against-angular2-components)

The problem case:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnutdw

Answer (score 0):

When you move your `<main>` tag into your component, then it is also being wrapped by your `<my-app>` parent tag from the index. The class is being applied correctly, it's just the parent tag that is making it not appear how you'd like.

Set `my-app` to have `width: 100%` to make it the full width or add the `container-fluid` class to the `my-app` element.